# Front end and back end not compatible - get more linker information

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, linker, linker-errors

while building a project in VisualStudio 2012 I get the error message

```
LINK : fatal error C1905: Front end and back end not compatible (must target same processor).
```

Checking the project manually does not help, all involved (static) libraries have been built for the same processor. I also added

```
/VERBOSE:lib and /VERBOSE
```

to command line to get some more information but this does not help, only additional output line I got by this was a stupid

```
Starting pass 1
```

So: any ideas how I can find out what causes this strange error message? How can I get more output from the linker?

Thanks!

Comment: Try turning on MSBuild verbosity.  Go to _Tools/Options/Projects and Solutions/Build and Run_.  You can set verbosity to diagnostic or detailed.

Comment: Make sure you are using a 64-bit version of the linker if you are producing a 64-bit output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Old question and I'm not sure whether anyone still need an answer. I had this problem with Visual Studio 2017.

Check paths for generated `.obj` files, especially when you use some `.cpp` files in more than one project (within solution) and/or use `%(RelativeDir)` variable in **Properties -> C/C++ -> Output Files -> Object File Name**. It happened to me with this path in **Object File Name** '$(IntDir)\%(RelativeDir)' and this `$(ProjectDir)Junk\$(Platform)\` in **Intermediate Directory**. Error gone when I moved `$(Platform)` part to **Object File Name**.

Old paths:
**Intermediate Directory**: `$(ProjectDir)Junk\$(Platform)\`.
**Object File Name**: `$(IntDir)\%(RelativeDir)`.

New paths:
**Intermediate Directory**: `$(ProjectDir)Junk\`.
**Object File Name**: `$(IntDir)$(Platform)\%(RelativeDir)`.

You can also specify **Object File Name** option for each file, shared between multiple projects to keep using old path (or if new paths configuration isn't working for you) and get rid of that error.